# how to access ansible newly created dictionary

Tags: ansible

I am following the example here http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/iam_policy_module.html to try to create a new AWS IAM user and then use this new user's username to attach an IAM policy to it.

The example:

```
task:
- name: Create Two Groups, Mario and Luigi
  iam:
    iam_type: group
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
     - Mario
     - Luigi
  register: new_groups

- name: Apply READ-ONLY policy to new groups that have been recently created
  iam_policy:
    iam_type: group
    iam_name: "{{ item.created_group.group_name }}"
    policy_name: "READ-ONLY"
    policy_document: readonlypolicy.json
    state: present
  with_items: "{{ new_groups.results }}"
```

I have adapted that to work with one user:

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: Create user lamda_ecr_delete
    iam:
      iam_type: user
      name: "{{ item }}"
      state: present
    with_items:
       - lambda_ecr_delete
    register: new_user

  - name: Apply ecr delete policy to newly created user
        iam_policy:
          iam_type: user
          iam_name: "{{ item.created_user.user_name }}"
          policy_name: "lambda_ecr_delete"
          policy_document: assets/aws-policies/lambda_ecr_delete.json
          state: present
        with_items: "{{ new_user.results }}"
```

But when I try to retrieve the username in the dictionary, `item.created_user` does not exist.

When I use `debug` to see the content of `{{ new_user.results }}` I can identify that it's a python list that contains a dict so I can probably access it with `[0]` and then call `invocation.module_args.name` which is a valid key.

This is the output for `debug: msg="{{ new_user.results }}"` when run with `--check`:

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": [
        {
            "_ansible_item_result": true, 
            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
            "_ansible_parsed": true, 
            "changed": false, 
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "iam_type": "user", 
                    "name": "lambda_ecr_delete", 
                    "state": "present"
                }
            }, 
            "item": "lambda_ecr_delete", 
            "msg": "remote module (iam) does not support check mode", 
            "skipped": true
        }
    ]
}
```

But that seems hackish. Is there a shortcut to access those module_args directly? Something as shown in the example with a `.created_user`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `item.user_meta.created_user.user_name` instead.

You could note that `created_user` is nested into `user_meta` if you inspect debug output of `new_user.results`. Looks like:

```
"user_meta": {
    "access_keys": null,
    "created_user": {
        "arn": "arn:aws:iam::<yourid>:user/test-ansible",
        "create_date": "2017-04-03T16:31:53.530Z",
        "path": "/",
        "user_id": "EXAMPLEKAJHFEXAMPLE",
        "user_name": "test-ansible"
    },
    "password": null
}
```

But be warned that on the second run `iam` module returns different output:

```
"user_name": "test-ansible"
```

instead of `user_meta` dictionary.

Comment: I have added the output of debug in my question. As you can see it is quite different from yours. I don't understand how. I have just started using ansible and could not find that in the docs. If there is an obvious reason for that and I missed it, feel free to just point me to some resources and I'll dig it myself.

Comment: There is a clear message for you in the output: `remote module (iam) does not support check mode`, so your task is just skipped by Ansible. Make a playground account in AWS for playbook testing and test them for real, not with `--check` parameter.